# Rails: Issue with recieving nested forms with has many through join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I seem to be having a problem with receiving products through my join table, it's giving me a strange error as it seems to be receiving no ID for my order. I can only assume that this is because the order has not been created yet, but I am creating the order during this step anyway, so the order doesn't have an ID yet. So this is my problem.

Here is the error I recieve:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrdersController#create

Couldn't find Product with ID=1 for Order with ID=

Rails.root: /BillingSystem
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:10:in `new'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"jE2wdERoxE7PKwBhN60KAfguxwAq8qdW4wbru51SMFg=",
 "order"=>{"client_id"=>"1",
 "products_attributes"=>{"1368396234677"=>{"id"=>"1",
 "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Order"}

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

New Order View:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <div id="dashboard">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <table id="go_back_link_container">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="go_back_link">
                        <%= link_to "<- Go Back", "/orders/view" %>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="user_display">
                        Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>.
                        <%= link_to "Log out", log_out_path %>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%= form_for @order, method: :post do |f| %>
            <% if @order.errors.any? %>
                <div class="error_messages">
                    <% for message in @order.errors.full_messages %>
                        * <%= message %> <br>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <p>
                <%= f.label 'Select The Client' %><br />
                <%= select :order, :client_id, Client.all().collect { |c| [ (c.firstname + " " + c.surname), c.id ] } %>
            </p>

            <%= f.fields_for :products do |pf| %>
                <% #render 'product_fields', f: builder %>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Product", f, :products %>

            <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
        <% end %>
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag :div, "* " + msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %><br />
        <% end %>
        <div id="copyright-notice"><div id="copyright_border">Copyright © Conner McCabe, all rights reserved.</div></div>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location="<%= root_url %>"
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Order Model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orderedproducts
    has_many :products, through: :orderedproducts
    has_one :client

    attr_accessible :client_id, :order_total, :delivery_date, :products, :products_attributes 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true

    before_save :generate_total

    def generate_total
        self.order_total = self.products.map(&:product_price).sum
    end
end
```

Orders Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def view
        @orders = Order.all
    end

    def new
        @order = Order.new
    end
    def create
        @order = Order.new(params[:order])
        if @order.save
            redirect_to '/orders/view', :notice => "Order Created!"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end
end
```

Product Fields Partial:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.select :id, Product.all().collect {|p| [ p.product_name, p.id ] } %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Products Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #This line makes these elements accessible outside of the class.
    attr_accessible :product_name, :product_price, :product_quantity, :product_supplier

    has_many :orderedproducts
    has_many :orders, through: :orderedproducts

    #These attributes ensure that the data entered for each element is valid and present.
    validates_presence_of :product_name
    validates_presence_of :product_price
    validates_numericality_of :product_price
    validates_presence_of :product_quantity
    validates_numericality_of :product_quantity
    validates_presence_of :product_supplier

end
```

Application Helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

Ordered Products Model:

```
class Orderedproduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :order_id, :product_id, :quantity_ordered
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I have listed every possible file that could contain an error, I know it's a bit excessive, but it's everything that is to do with it and better I include it than not at all.

I also followed this railscast guide: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised
To get to where I am, I edited it slightly so that it was suitable for my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue on a project, except the relation was singular. The problem is that ActiveRecord is looking for an existing association; something like order.products.find(1). Since order is as new record this doesn't work.

You could create your own products_attributes= method and define the correct behaviour. But I think that you could just use nested attributes for the join model (Orderedproduct) instead of Product.

```
class Order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orderedproducts
end
```

Then adjust the form fields appropriately. In the new form

`f.fields_for :products do |pf|` becomes `f.fields_for :orderedproducts do |pf|`

In the fields partial

`<%= f.select :id, Product.all().collect {|p| [ p.product_name, p.id ] } %>` becomes `<%= f.select :product_id, Product.all().collect {|p| [ p.product_name, p.id ] } %>`